# Firebase remote config, cant get value. Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have created some test project for learning Firebase remote config. This is settings in firebase https://monosnap.com/file/0xgQCL7oo7lyOjBs8CG3kZO0szBXh6 . Bellow my code:

```
final FirebaseRemoteConfig config = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
            FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                    .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    .build();
            config.setConfigSettings(configSettings);

            String onlineVersion = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString("android_current_version");// empty string
```

I dont know why i cant get value from firebase

Comment: you have to fetch your remote config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to fetch the remote config first:

```
config.fetch(cacheExpiration)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Succeeded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // After config data is successfully fetched, it must be activated before newly fetched
                // values are returned.
                mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            String onlineVersion = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString("android_current_version");// empty string
        }
    })
```

In the "onComplete" method, you can get the remote config info

check this: [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android?hl=es-419)

Comment: if fetch is failed, is firebase return empty or default value? @MaxPinto

Comment: activateFetched() is deprecated now, use mRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate() no need extra activate